# Using NULL with Hibernate Filter and HQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, filter, null, annotations

I am using Hibernate filters as defined below:

```
@FilterDef(
    name = "DeptFilter",
    parameters = {
        @ParamDef(name = "schoolCode", type = "string"),
        @ParamDef(name = "deptCode", type = "string")
    }
)
@Filter(
    name = "DeptFilter",
    condition = "(:schoolCode = schoolCode and (deptCode IS NULL or :deptCode = deptCode))"
)
```

In my case, some data is available to all Departments, In such cases, I have kept dept value as NULL.

```
Filter sessionFilter = session.enableFilter("DeptFilter");
sessionFilter.setParameter("schoolCode", schoolId.getSchoolCode());
sessionFilter.setParameter("deptCode", schoolId.getDeptCode());

Query query = session.createQuery("from Inbox where assignedTo = :assignedTo ")
        .setParameter("assignedTo", userRole);
```

When I am passing NULL value as Dept Code parameter. I am getting following Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Filter [DeptFilter] parameter [deptCode] value not set
```

I have also tried to use Empty String (""), But this case I am getting no record with blank/Null dept Id.

Can you please let me know how to handle NULL values in filter.

Regards,

Shirish

Comment: Can you use a criteria instead ? you can easily use  

criteria.add(deptCode == null ? Restrictions.isNull("deptCode") : Restrictions.eq("deptCode", deptCode));